# Solving 2x2 diagonally dominant matrix systems (non-symmetric)

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, gaussian-elimination

I have a linear system of the form $Ax=b$ where $A\in \mathbb{R}^{2\times2}, b\in \mathbb{R}^{2\times1}$. A is diagonally dominant and non-symmetric. This is a "kernel" that I am using to solve a bigger problem, and I want to do it with the fastest numerically stable way. So far I am using Gaussian Elimination as a straight forward choice, needs 4 mutiplications/divisions and 3 additions/substractions. Before I start trying out different methods on my own, I wonder if this has been studied in depth.

Comment: Is $A$ constant and $b$ varying?

Comment: A is not constant, but it is of the form A={1,a1;a2,1} (in Matlab notation) where a1,a2 << 1. b can be varying

Comment: If you mean $|a_1|,|a_2|$ much smaller than 1, then the condition of $A$ is pretty close to 1, so Gaussian elimination should be pretty stable. I am guessing you would be hard pressed to beat 3 */, 4 +-.

Comment: I meant 4 */, 3 +-.

Comment: Gaussian elimination might run you into some trouble if, in the process, you divide by either $a_1$ or $a_2$.

Comment: The only division in Gaussian elimination (in this example) is at the back substitution phase and that involves dividing by the determinant $1-a_1 a_2$ which, if I understand correctly, is pretty close to 1, so there should be no issue?

Answer (score 1):

$2 \times 2$ systems are pretty easy; if $A$ is diagonally dominant by a sufficient margin, you should have no problems with numerical stability. If we have
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&a_1\\a_2&1}, \quad b = \pmatrix{b_1\\b_2}
$$
Then the solution will be
$$
x = A^{-1}b = \frac{1}{1 - a_1 a_2} \pmatrix{1&-a_1\\-a_2&1} \pmatrix{b_1\\b_2} = 
\frac 1{1-a_1 a_2}\pmatrix{b_1 - a_1 b_2\\-a_1b_1 + b_2}
$$
I don't think you can do much better than that.  The only step that could potentially go wrong is dividing by $1 - a_1 a_2$, but if $A$ is "diagonally dominant enough", that isn't a problem.

Gaussian elimination should work just as well in getting you the answer (and apparently does a multiplication better, since this takes 5 multiplications and 3 additions).

Comment: The explicit solution uses one more multiplication than Gaussian elimination... (assuming I am counting correctly)

Comment: @copper.hat I counted four at first, but you're right, mine has 5.  Does elimination actually save a multiplication?

Comment: I counted 4 for GE, also, the only division is by the determinant $1-a_1 a_2$ which seems unavoidable either way.

Comment: Ah, I was messing up one of the steps.  Makes sense now.  It's still a bit counterintuitive that the explicit solution is a step slower.

Comment: I agree. It is because $[A]_{11} = 1$, so there is no need to divide to compute $x_1$. The 'cost' is that there is room for more floating point 'noise'.